# Простой калькулятор на Android

Tags: android, java, eval, калькулятор

Здравствуйте.

Изучаю разработку под Андроид, пишу банальные задачки (сейчас - калькулятор).
И вот собственно встал вопрос - строку с выражением я сформировал, как мне теперь её посчитать? Если бы у меня сложный калькулятор, то использовал бы методы обратной польской записи и другие уже известные алгоритмы. Но у меня +, -, *, /. В скриптовых языках я бы использовал что-то вроде eval(), а вот тут запнулся...

Помогите, если сталкивались, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="   1   " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="   2   " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="   3   " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="   +   " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="   -   " />
</TableRow>

    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="   4   " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="   5   " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="   6   " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="   /   " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="   *   " />
</TableRow>

   <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="   7   " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="   8   " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="  9   " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="   0   " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="   =   " />

</TableRow>

  <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Decimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button23"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Binary" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button22"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Clear" />
</TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity.java**

```
package calc.calc;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CalcActivity extends Activity {

    /**Переменная текстбокса*/
    EditText calcDialogDisplay;

    /**Переменные кнопок*/
    TextView binary;
    TextView allClear;
    TextView seven;
    TextView eight;
    TextView nine;
    TextView division;
    TextView four;
    TextView five;
    TextView six;
    TextView multiply;
    TextView one;
    TextView two;
    TextView three;
    TextView subtract;
    TextView decimal;
    TextView zero;
    TextView equals;
    TextView addition;

    /**Результат который заносится в масив для обработки*/
    ArrayList<Float> result = new ArrayList<Float>();

    /**Первое введенное число*/
    float number1;

    /**Второе введенное число*/
    float number2;

    int currentOperation = 0;
    int nextOperation;

    /**Прибавление*/
    final static int ADD = 1;

    /**Вычитание*/
    final static int SUBTRACT = 2;

    /**Умножение*/
    final static int MULTIPLY = 3;

    /**Деление*/
    final static int DIVISION = 4;

    /**Равно*/
    final static int EQUALS = 5;

    /**Нахождение целого значение из двоичного числа*/
    final static int DECIMAL = 6;

    /**Нахождение двоичного числа из целого*/
    final static int BINARY = 7;

    final static int CLEAR = 1;
    final static int DONT_CLEAR = 0;
    int clearCalcDisplay = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        calcDialogDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        binary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button23);
        allClear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button22);
        seven = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        eight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        nine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button13);
        division =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        four = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        five = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        six =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        multiply = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button10);
        one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        two = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        three = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        subtract = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        decimal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button16);
        zero = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button20);
        equals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button14);
        //addition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addition);
        calcDialogDisplay.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true));

        registerListeners();
    }

    /*Обработка нажатия на экран*/
    public void registerListeners () {

        seven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("7");
            }
        });

        eight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("8");

            }
        });

        nine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("9");

            }
        });

        division.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calcLogic(DIVISION);                    
            }
        });

        allClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                number1 = 0;
                number2 = 0;
                result.removeAll(result);
                currentOperation = 0;
                nextOperation = 0;                  
            }
        });

    four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
            }
            clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
            calcDialogDisplay.append("4");

        }
    });

    five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
            }
            clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
            calcDialogDisplay.append("5");

        }
    });

    six.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
            }
            clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
            calcDialogDisplay.append("6");
        }
    });

    zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
            }
            clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
            calcDialogDisplay.append("0");
        }
    });

    decimal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calcLogic(DECIMAL);
        }
    });

    multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calcLogic(MULTIPLY);
        }
    });

    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
            }
            clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
            calcDialogDisplay.append("1");

        }
    });

    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
            }
            clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
            calcDialogDisplay.append("2");

        }
    });

    three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
            }
            clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
            calcDialogDisplay.append("3");

        }
    });

    subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calcLogic(SUBTRACT);
        }               
    });

    equals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calcLogic(EQUALS);

        }
    });

    binary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calcLogic(BINARY);

        }
    });
}

    /*Функция перевода из десятичного в двоичное значение*/
    private float decToBin(float bin) {  
        int i, b;  
        long result = 0;

         for(i=0; bin > 0; i++)  {
            b = (int) (bin % 2);  
            bin = (bin-b)/2;
            result += b * Math.pow(10,i);
        }
         return result;
    }

    /*Функция перевода из двличного в десятичное значение*/
    private float binToDec(float dec) {
        int result = 0;
        int mult = 1;

        while(dec > 0) {
            result += mult * ((int)dec % 10);
            dec /= 10;
            mult *= 2;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /*Функция расчета введенных значений*/
    private void calcLogic(int operator) {

    result.add(Float.parseFloat(calcDialogDisplay.getText().toString()));

    if (operator != EQUALS) {
        nextOperation = operator;
    }else if (operator == EQUALS){
        nextOperation = 0;
    }

    switch (currentOperation) {

    /*Прибавление*/
        case ADD:               
            number1 = result.get(0);
            number2 = result.get(1);

            result.removeAll(result);

            result.add(number1 + number2);

            calcDialogDisplay.setText(String.format("%.0f", result.get(0)));
            break;

      /*Вычитание*/      
        case SUBTRACT:
            number1 = result.get(0);
            number2 = result.get(1);

            result.removeAll(result);

            result.add(number1 - number2);

            calcDialogDisplay.setText(String.format("%.0f", result.get(0)));
            break;

      /*Умножение*/
        case MULTIPLY:
            number1 = result.get(0);
            number2 = result.get(1);

            result.removeAll(result);

            result.add(number1 * number2);

            calcDialogDisplay.setText(String.format("%.0f", result.get(0)));
            break;
       /*Деление*/     
        case DIVISION:
            number1 = result.get(0);
            number2 = result.get(1);

            result.removeAll(result);

            result.add(number1 / number2);

            calcDialogDisplay.setText(String.format("%.0f", result.get(0)));
            break;

        /*Получание двоичного числа*/    
        case DECIMAL:
             number2 = result.get(1);

             result.removeAll(result);

             result.add(decToBin(number2));

             calcDialogDisplay.setText(String.format("%.0f", result.get(0)));
            break;

       /*Получение десятичного числа*/
        case BINARY:
             number2 = result.get(1);

             result.removeAll(result);

             result.add(binToDec(number2));

             calcDialogDisplay.setText(String.format("%.0f", result.get(0)));
            break;
    }

    clearCalcDisplay = CLEAR;
    currentOperation = nextOperation;
    if (operator == EQUALS) {
        number1 = 0;
        number2 = 0;
        result.removeAll(result);
    }
}

}
```

Когда - то давно прогал для собеседования

Comment: Жесть

    three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
            }
            clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
            calcDialogDisplay.append("3");
        }
    });

Comment: индусский код)

Comment: @dajver бывает. и даже в продакшене)

Comment: Спасибо! Кстати, взяли на работу после собеседования?)

Comment: нет не взяли, видимо индусский код виноват)

Answer (score 0):

Парсите строку и складывайте числа, если после числа идет пробел(ы), или "+","-" если пробелы и "*", "/" то сначала выполните действие и посмотрите дальше (рекурсия), если потом число, то складывайте, если нет повторите.

Comment: может есть что то встроенное, по моему в javax что то такое есть, но поддерживается ли в андроиде не знаю

Comment: мне тоже кажется, что рекурсией проще всего...
Если найдены приоритетные операторы, то выполняем их действие над выражениями, значения которых рассчитываются этой же функцей(в рекурсии)